# How can I Combine Regular and Italicized Text in the same line in iText 7?

Tags: itext7, typography

I have code like so to write out a line of text:

```
Paragraph parExecSummHeader = new Paragraph();
. . .
parExecSummHeader.Add("AUTHOR PROFILE ANALYSIS OF " + docNameOnly);
```

I want the value in *docNameOnly* to be italicized.

Based on an old post [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-make-a-single-letter-bold-within-a-word) (which apparently doesn't apply to iText 7), you can do it something like this:

```
Chunk chunky = new Chunk(docNameOnly, italicize);
parExecSummHeader.Add("AUTHOR PROFILE ANALYSIS OF " + parExecSummHeader.Chunky);
```

...but that doesn't seem to work with iText 7.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this bit of fanciness?

Comment: The link you posted - https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-make-a-single-letter-bold-within-a-word - points to iText 7 examples, so it should *apply to iText 7*...

Comment: As an aside, `"AUTHOR PROFILE ANALYSIS OF " + parExecSummHeader.Chunky` is a string concatenation, not at all what you want.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the +500! That wasn't necessary at all, in particular for such a short answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iText 7 the `Text` class has replaced the `Chunk` class of iText 5. Thus, to add differently styled parts to a paragraph, use `Text` instances, e.g. like this

```c#
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Add("AUTHOR PROFILE ANALYSIS OF ");
paragraph.Add(new Text("B. Clay Shannon").SetItalic());
doc.Add(paragraph);
```

for

[image: screen shot]